# PowerShell, How can I open an url in existing browser tab?

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, browser, navigation

I want to make a powershell script, that will:

1. Run Chrome
2. Open a google.com website
3. Stay some time on it
4. Go from google.com ===> bing.com in the same tab.

So this is the code, that works for me, it's run Chrome and open google.com website in the tab:
Start-Process "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"

The main problem, I don't know how to open new link in the same tab. I found this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx , but I am a total noobie and can't use this information properly. 
Is there someone, who could help me? Please?

Comment: That article is for Internet Explorer which can be scripted directly from within PowerShell. You probably need [Selenium WebDriver for PowerShell](https://sepsx.codeplex.com/) and `driver.navigate().goToURL('http://www.example.com')`. I didn't use it so not posting as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

you Can use below powershell command to open URL in new tab  in any Browser

Start-Process -FilePath Chrome -ArgumentList https://www.google.co.in

Where

Filepath - Browser type (Chrome , Explorer)

ArgumentList - URL

Comment: add enough solution.